# write data in binary format in Files in Android

Tags: android, file-io, data-storage

hi all:
making a sample application in which we can store data on File and then could Read it.,
m using the following code.:
**Code to Write:**

```
OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("finear.fin", 0));
        out.write(data); //data is String variable
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data has been Saved! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**Code to Read:**

```
instream = openFileInput("finear.fin");
if(instream!=null)
{
InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
String dataRead = buffreader.readLine();
}
```

Now problem is: The Data is stored in simple Text Form but i want that no one could read my data from that file and it should store the data in some binary form or some symbols type format so that when one opens the file in windows it should not display my text stored in the file or should display some other data.. BUT also that data could be readable in String form when i read. PLease Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Android's internal storage, which is private to your application:

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

Here you can find the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: so you mean to say that there is a private area in the phone internal storage. by the way my default path is   /data/data/package/files/filename  So this file wont be accessible when we connect the phone with my Computer?

Comment: Saving important data unencrypted in internal storage is equally unsecure. There are zillions (well, not so many) ways to read them. And in a rooted phone is as easy as it gets.

Comment: Yes, it wont be accessible when you connect the phone. Maybe it will be readable if the phone is rooted.

Comment: As Federico Erostarbe says, encyption adds a layer of security. You can use the two ways together.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt the String before saving it to the stream and the other way to read it. If you want your file's contents to be unreadable, encryption would be a win.